# Abrir Dialog no primefaces assim que e a tela abrir

Tags: primefaces

Tenho uma tela de login onde tenho um Dialog com os campos Login e Senha. Gostaria que ele abrisse assim que a tela fosse aberta. Li que a partir da versão 4.1 do primefaces tenho que chamar o Dialog dessa forma: `PF('widgetVar').show()` mas aonde posso chamar esse Dialog?

Comment: Use o atributo visible=true do próprio componente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode simplesmente adicionar o atributo `visible="true"` que automaticamente o `<p:dialog>` se mostrará aberto quando a página for acessada.

Outra maneira além da que o Rafael respondeu é fazer isso via jQuery (o PrimeFaces já inclui no projeto):

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        PF('widgetVar').show();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 6):

Com o `remoteCommand`você consegue fazer isso. Segue um exemplo.

```
<p:dialog widgetVar="dlg" width="300" height="300" modal="false">
    teste dialog
</p:dialog>
<p:remoteCommand autoRun="true" oncomplete="PF('dlg').show();"/>
```